# Installing Cloud9 on Ubuntu 14.04 - Cannot find module

Tags: cloud, nodejs

I am trying to install Cloud9 IDE on my own Ubuntu server, following [these](https://github.com/c9/core/) instructions.

So what I have done essentially so far is cloning the project in my system, installing nodejs-legacy (C9 here requires the nodejs executable has the name `node`) and running the install script of C9. After some trial and error, installation went fine with no errors. But when time came to run the `server.js` file, I get this error: `{ [Error: Cannot find module 'connect/lib/utils'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }`

So that's the lot of my problem... any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Ran into the same issue. Here's how I fixed it:

For whatever reason, the default install script seemed to fail to add a number of the modules.  I iteratively added the modules as errors referred to their absence by running `npm install nameofmodule` (in your case 'connect') then attempting to start c9 again.

Eventually this resulted in the c9 IDE starting but more references to missing modules being generated. I repeated the above, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> killing the ide, installing the module and relaunching until I got to what appears to be a fully functional state.

Web browsing to the IDE and taking action results in output to the console you launched the IDE from so keep an eye on that for any more missing modules once you are up and running.